# Customizing Skeleton responsive layout

Tags: layout, responsive-design, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm working on a site that uses the [Get Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com) responsive boilerplate and am trying to create this [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB7NJ.jpg). The grey squares represent images.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Will grey box width and height is fixed or should grow / shrink based on the content ?

Comment: The plan is to keep the grey boxes a fixed width/height (280px).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic structure, you can alter the height / width

```
<style>
    .greybox{   
        background-color:#eee;
        width:100%;
        height:200px;
        margin-bottom:4%;
    }
  </style>

<div class="u-full-width">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="four columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="greybox">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="greybox">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="four columns">
        <p>Yourself off its pleasant ecstatic now law. Ye their mirth seems of songs. Prospect out bed contempt separate. Her inquietude our shy yet sentiments collecting. Cottage fat beloved himself arrived old. Grave widow hours among him ﻿no you led. Power had these met least nor young. Yet match drift wrong his our. 
New had happen unable uneasy. Drawings can followed improved out sociable not. Earnestly so do instantly pretended. See general few civilly amiable pleased account carried. Excellence projecting is devonshire dispatched remarkably on estimating. Side in so life past. Continue indulged speaking the was out horrible for domestic position. Seeing rather her you not esteem men settle genius excuse. Deal say over you age from. Comparison new ham melancholy son themselves. 
Affronting everything discretion men now own did. Still round match we to. Frankness pronounce daughters remainder extensive has but. Happiness cordially one determine concluded fat. Plenty season beyond by hardly giving of. Consulted or acuteness dejection an smallness if. Outward general passage another as it. Very his are come man walk one next. Delighted prevailed supported too not remainder perpetual who furnished. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="four columns">
       <div class="row">
            <div class="greybox">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="greybox">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```